# Is there an etymon for scam?

Tags: etymology

Is the word *escamotage* which is found in English dictionaries etymologically related to the word *scam*?

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @anekename. 
Sharing your research helps everybody - show what you've found already, and explain what it is you don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

Not according to the online sources I looked at.

From [Etymonline.com:](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=scam)

> **scam**
>   1963, noun and verb, U.S. slang, a carnival term, of unknown origin. Perhaps related to 19c. British slang *scamp* "cheater, swindler" (see **scamp** (n.)).

At the same website's entry for [**scamp**](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=scamp) we find the following:

> **scamp** (n.)
>   1782, "highway robber," probably from dialectal verb *scamp* "to roam" (1753, perhaps from 16c.), shortened from **scamper**. Used affectionately in sense "rascal" since 1808.

At [Worthless word for the day](http://home.comcast.net/~wwftd/Frame1.html) (one of just two easily locatable sources of definitions that included this word), I found **escamotage** defined [thus:](http://home.comcast.net/~wwftd/def.htm#escamotage)

> **escamotage**
>   [fr. F. *escamoter* to juggle, conjure, make vanish]
>   /es kah mo tazh/  juggling, sleight of hand, trickery

Comment: The OED agrees that the origin is 'obscure', though it also dates *scam* from the mid 1960s and as American. I think that some high-profile planned fraudulent bankruptcies of the post 1966 period are significant in the word's emergence.

Comment: Curious -- I don't recall that "scam" ever seemed like a newly-coined word to me.  But I can't say when I first heard it, either.

Answer (score 1):

*Escamotage* seems pretty obscure to have given birth to "scam". Try this on for size:

The adopted (Fr) word "camouflage" - according to OED: evolved from a slang expression borrowed from the (It) *camuffare* - to disguise, or deceive.

OK, now picture this... Epic numbers of Italian immigrants arriving in the US at the turn of the 20th century.  They are easy pickin's for swindlers, in their new home. Pretty soon, they will encounter the word "sham" (False, misleading... Origins also vague - late 18th cent. AmE)

But, in trying to explain the concept to Mrs. Mangiafaccia, (whose English "isa no so gooda") the Italian and English words are accidentally combined - giving birth to the mutation "scam".

(Unsubstantiated, but possibly, coulda be.)

Comment: _Sham_ is late 1600s in BrE. I'd never considered _scam_ as being 'youthful', so imagine my surprise when _flim-flam_ turns out to be mid 1500s.  A scam, a sham, a flim-flam - in that order.